# Is it possible to defined ion-item attributes globally?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I'm using the Ionic Framework and I wonder if it's possible to defined global options for [ion-item](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item) elements.

In .html files I got

```
<ion-item lines="none"></ion-item>
```

I would like every ion-item to have the "lines=nones". Is there a way to define it globally so that I could only use:

```
<ion-item></ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve that would be by adding the following in the `variables.scss` file:

```
ion-item {
  --inner-border-width: 0px;
}
```

Although to be honest, if in the future you want to show an `ion-item` with lines it may be hard to remember/debug why the lines are not shown when adding an `<ion-item></ion-item>` to the view.

So if the only difference is one attribute, I guess it'd be better to just be explicit and add `lines="none"` on each `ion-item` that you want to show without lines.

```
<ion-item lines="none"></ion-item>
<ion-item lines="none"></ion-item>
...
<ion-item></ion-item>
<ion-item></ion-item>
```